# Cut a list of length `n` into even number `m` of adjacent sublists of odd length in all possible ways?

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

Consider a list with all different entries of length `n`, i.e. for `n=6`:

```
list = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

I would like to have a function `fun[lst_,m_]` that given this list will return a list of lists containing all possible ways to cut `list` into `m` adjacent sublists, such that the length of each sublist is odd:

```
fun[list,0]
```

> `False`

```
fun[list,2]
```

> `{ {{1,2,3,4,5},{6}} , {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}} , {{1},{2,3,4,5,6}} }`

```
fun[list,4]
```

> `{ {{1,2,3},{4},{5},{6}} , {{1},{2,3,4},{5},{6}} ,
>    {{1},{2},{3,4,5},{6}} , {{1},{2},{3},{4,5,6}} }`

```
fun[list,6]
```

> `{ {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}} }`

Again, notice that the resulting list contains lists that divide `list` into an even number `m` of sublists, each of which has odd length.

Is there a quick way to implement this in Mathematica?

**EDIT**

Due to popular demand, behold my monstrosity:

```
fun[lst_, m_] := Module[{prt,odd, tmp, tmp2, prm, pt},
   prt = IntegerPartitions[Length[lst], {m}];
   tmp = {};
   Do[
    odd = True;
    Do[
     If[EvenQ[prt[[i, j]]], odd = False;];
     , {j, 1, Length[prt[[i]]]}];
    If[odd, AppendTo[tmp, prt[[i]]];];
    , {i, 1, Length[prt]}];
   tmp2 = {};
   Do[
    prm = Permutations[tmp[[i]]] // DeleteDuplicates;
    Do[
     pt = {};
     Do[
      AppendTo[pt, lst[[Total[prm[[j, 1 ;; q - 1]]] + 1 ;; Total[prm[[j, 1 ;; q]]]]]];
      , {q, 1, Length[prm[[j]]]}];
     AppendTo[tmp2, pt];
     , {j, 1, Length[prm]}];
    , {i, 1, Length[tmp]}];
   tmp2
   ];
```

Comment: Please show at least one example of what you have tried thus far.

Comment: probably you want to use `IntegerPartitions` and `Permutations`

Comment: @Edmund I did warn you that it would not be pretty! ^^ See the edit of my question.

Comment: Yes. It is less-than ideal. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[fun]
fun[lst_, m_] := Module[{lengths = Join @@ (Permutations /@ 
       IntegerPartitions[Length@lst, {m}, Range[1, Length@lst, 2]])}, 
  Internal`PartitionRagged[lst, #] & /@ lengths]


fun[Range[6], 0]
```

> {}

```
fun[Range[6], 2]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6}}, {{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}

```
fun[Range[6], 4]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}, {{1}, {2, 3, 4}, {5}, {6}}, {{1}, {2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4, 5, 6}}}

```
fun[Range[6], 6]
```

> {{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}}

Comment: This is amazingly short, thank you!

Comment: @Kagaratsch, thank you for the accept.

Comment: what should I change if I want to switch `m` from even to odd?

Comment: @Kagaratsch, if you still want to have each sublist to have an odd length, you don't have to change anything (`m` could be even or odd). If you want  to have each sublist to have even length, use `Range[2, Length@lst, 2]` instead of `Range[1, Length@lst, 2]`.

Comment: Elegant... +1..